# Why am I getting error although everything is declared well?

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc, calloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int n;

    printf("Enter the no of elements you want in an array1:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("The no of elements in array 1 would be %d",n);

    ptr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if(ptr==NULL){
        printf("Memory not alloted ");
    }
    else{
        printf("Memory successfully alloted using malloc");
    }

    printf("The elements of array 1 are:");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        ptr[i]=2*i;
        printf("%d",ptr[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);
    printf("Memory has been successfully freed\n");

    int *ptr1,n1;
    printf("Enter the no of elements you want in an array2:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("The no of elements in array 2  would be %d",n1);

    ptr1=(int*)calloc(n1,sizeof(int));
    if(ptr1==NULL){
        printf("Memory not alloted \n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Memory successfully alloted using calloc\n");
    }

    printf("The elements of array 2 are:");
    for(int j=0;j<n1;j++){
        ptr1[j]=j+2;
        printf("%d",ptr1[j]);
    }

    ptr1=realloc(ptr1,2*n1*sizeof(int));
    printf("Memory successfully reallocated using realloc");
    printf("The array after reallocation is:");
    
    for(int k=0;k<2*n1;k++){
        ptr1[k]=k+2;
        printf("%d",ptr1[k]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code by declaring everything but still I am getting a compile error:

```
main.cpp:50:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
     ptr1=realloc(ptr1,2*n1*sizeof(int));
          ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Could anyone tell me what is  the error and how I should correct it.?

Comment: C++ is not C.  `*.cpp` is typically the name of a C++ program.  The compiler seems to be inferring from the name that you want to compile as C++.

Comment: Probably the correct solution is `mv main.cpp main.c`.

Comment: try to add on the realloc function (int*) as : `(int*)realloc(ptr1, 2 * n1 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Only if they really want C++ instead of C, @NevoGoldman.  The two are different languages in many more ways than this, and it is a grave error to compile C code as C++ unless that code was painstakingly crafted to conform to both languages simultaneously -- which is difficult and rarely worth the effort.  C or C++: choose **one**.

Comment: I don't see any problem with not casting. In fact you also should **not** cast to `(int )*` in the `malloc` and `calloc` lines.

Comment: ... in C, that is.

Comment: Yes, that was assuming that we're talking C here. I'm going by the tag and the include headers, and assume that @WilliamPursell was correct.

Answer (score 5):

The `realloc` function is returning a `void *` which you're assigning to a `int *`.  In C, conversions between a `void *` and any other object pointer can be performed without a cast.  However, the name of the file you're compiling has a .cpp extension.  Most compilers will see that and compile it as a C++ program, and in C++ a conversion from `void *` to `int *` requires a cast.

Since the code appears to be completely C and you've used the C tag, I'm assuming you want to compile a C program.  That being the case, rename the main.cpp file to main.c and it should compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

You compile the C program using C++ compiler. You need to:

1. If usung g++:
   add `-xc` command line option
2. If msvc:
   add `/Tc` or better `/TC` command line option
3. Or simply rename `.cpp` files to `.c` (it may not work depending on the command line options)

Do not cast or do any other magic. It is very bad to compile C program using C++ compiler as they are different languages and many things differ.